# Учет группы которую можно отбросить в некоторых случаях

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Текущее состояние выражения:

```
^(.*)\/(.*)(?=\s\[(\d{1,})\sиз\s(\d{1,})\])
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы 3я и 4я группа не захватывались если их нет, а когда есть, то захватывать?

На данный момент если 3я или 4я группа отсутствует, то строка вообще не матчится.

Пример данных для тестов:

```
Триплексоголик ТВ-2 / xxxHolic: Kei [13 из 13]
Золотое Божество ТВ-2 / Golden Kamuy TV-2 [11 из 12]
Космический линкор Тирамису ТВ-2 / Uchuu Senkan Tiramisu TV-2 [12 из 13]
Шестизарядник / Six Shooter
```

Comment: Нельзя, групп всегда постоянное количество, но можно сделать саму группу опциональной (квантификатор `?` после группы), тогда при ее отсутствии во входной строке будет захватываться пустая подстрока

Comment: Приложи исходный текст на котором проверяется.

Comment: [`/^([^\/]+)\/(.+?)(?=\[(\d+)\hиз\h(\d+)]|$)/m`](https://regex101.com/r/HULsHZ/3)

Comment: Я проведу тесты на вашем выражении, сообщу если что-то пойдет не так.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie: Запишите как ответ, но я немного доделал ваше выражение до такого вида: `^([^\/]+)\s\/\s(.+?)(?=\s\[(\d+)\sиз\s(\d+)+?\W+?|\]|$)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначальный вариант:

```
/^([^\/]+)\/(.+?)(?=\[(\d+)\hиз\h(\d+)]|$)/m
```

В комментариях вы написали, что сделали небольшие изменения. Не совсем понимаю к чему эти изменения с добавлением квантификатора `\W`, а также в логике между выбором конца строки (`$`), и захватом 3-ей и 4-ой групп.

Если речь об избавлении выделенных групп от пробелов, то можно привести к такому виду:

```
/^([^\/]+)\s\/\s(.+?)(?=\s\[(\d+)\hиз\h(\d+)]|$)/m
```

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/HULsHZ/4).

Подробны детали по выражению:

- `^` - начало строки
- `([^\/]+)` - первая группа, захватывает все до слэша (`/`)
- `\s\/\s` - два пробела, между которыми стоит слэш
- `(.+?)` - вторая захватывающая группа
- `(?=` - начало позитивного просмотра вперед

  - далее идет захват конструкции - `\s\[(\d+)\hиз\h(\d+)]`, или (`|`) же конец строки (`$`)
- `)` - конец позитивного просмотра вперед

Comment: Дело не в пробелах, провел тесты, выражение иногда захватывало строки где в конце было [1 из 45 + SP]

Comment: @LLENN, об этом стоило указать в примечании, посмотрите на этот [вариант](https://regex101.com/r/HULsHZ/6)